# Using distinct keyword with join

Tags: sql, oracle

My professor has given me an assignment.

> Write a query that will produce the
>   snum values of all salespeople
>   (suppress the duplicates) with orders
>   in the Orders table.

**SalesPeople**

Snum number(4)
Sname varchar2(10)
City varchar2(10)
Comm number(3,2)

**Customer**

Cnum number(4)
Cname varchar2(10)
City varchar2(10)
Rating number(4)
Snum number(4)

**Orders**

Onum number(4)
Amt number(7,2)
Odate date
Cnum number(4)
Snum number(4)

I am not sure if I have understood the question completely.

I have written the query using join.

```
select distinct s.snum,onum
from salespeople s, ordrs o
where s.snum = o.snum
order by snum;
```

and the output is

```
      SNUM       ONUM
---------- ----------
      1001       3003
      1001       3008
      1001       3011
      1002       3005
      1002       3007
      1002       3010
      1004       3002
      1007       3001
      1007       3006
```

But I don't want  SNUM to be repeated. Can someone point me in a right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a foreign key constraint on Orders.snum (-> SalesPeople.snum)?

Answer (score 4):

The question asks you to "Write a query that will produce the snum values of all salespeople (suppress the duplicates) with orders in the Orders table" - it doesn't specify that you need to include the order numbers. (It implies that you *don't* need the order numbers, since by including them you will duplicate the snum values.)

Given that snum appears on the Orders table, it should be relatively simple to SELECT a DISTINCT list of SNUM values FROM the ORDERS table.

Answer (score 1):

In your query remove onum from the SELECT -

```
select distinct s.snum
from salespeople s, ordrs o
where s.snum = o.snum
order by snum;
```

This should display only the distinct snum.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to select from 1 table:

```
select distinct o.snum
from ordrs o
order by o.snum;
```

NB I have kept the order by clause, but it isn't strictly needed to answer the question as it was given.

Answer (score 1):

Both answer above seems correct but it seems that

```
select distinct snum
from ordrs
order by snum
```

or

```
select snum
from ordrs
group by snum
order by snum
```

would be more efficient because we dont need to read the salespeople. This is acceptable if there is a foreign key constraint on snum in the table ordrs.

NB: Tony just answered when i was writing this. I would 100% agree with him :)

Answer (score 0):

And it can also be easily done with a subquery instead of a join:

```
select s.snum
from salespeople s
where exists (
  select 1
  from ordrs
  where snum = s.snum
);
```

which basically says: give me all snum's that have at least 1 matching record in the ordrs table.